# Creating A New Variable or Column in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

The given dataset `cust_rating` has 3 columns i.e `rating`, `food_rating`, `service_rating`.

I want to create a new variable `avg_rating`.

```
import pandas as pd
cust_rating = pd.read_csv('https://query.data.world/s/ILc-P4llUraMaYN6N6Bdw7p6kUvHnj')

cust_rating['avg_rating'] = round(#Type your code here.)

print(cust_rating.head(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, try:

```
cust_rating['avg_rating'] = cust_rating.filter(like='rating').mean(axis=1)
cust_rating
```

Output:

```
     userID  placeID  rating  food_rating  service_rating  avg_rating
0     U1077   135085       2            2               2    2.000000
1     U1077   135038       2            2               1    1.666667
2     U1077   132825       2            2               2    2.000000
3     U1077   135060       1            2               2    1.666667
4     U1068   135104       1            1               2    1.333333
...     ...      ...     ...          ...             ...         ...
1249  U1043   132630       1            1               1    1.000000
1250  U1011   132715       1            1               0    0.666667
1251  U1068   132733       1            1               0    0.666667
1252  U1068   132594       1            1               1    1.000000
1253  U1068   132660       0            0               0    0.000000

[1254 rows x 6 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple case of [mean](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) across required columns

```
import pandas as pd
cust_rating = pd.read_csv('https://query.data.world/s/ILc-P4llUraMaYN6N6Bdw7p6kUvHnj')

cust_rating['avg_rating'] = cust_rating.loc[:,[c for c in cust_rating.columns if "rating" in c]].mean(axis=1)

cust_rating.head(10)
```

|  | userID | placeID | rating | food_rating | service_rating | avg_rating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | U1077 | 135085 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | U1077 | 135038 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1.66667 |
| 2 | U1077 | 132825 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | U1077 | 135060 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1.66667 |
| 4 | U1068 | 135104 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1.33333 |
| 5 | U1068 | 132740 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | U1068 | 132663 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 7 | U1068 | 132732 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 8 | U1068 | 132630 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 9 | U1067 | 132584 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |

Answer (score 0):

```py
cust_rating['avg_rating'] = round( (cust_rating['rating']+cust_rating['food_rating']+cust_rating['service_rating'])/3,1 )

    userID  placeID rating  food_rating service_rating  avg_rating
0   U1077   135085  2   2   2   2.0
1   U1077   135038  2   2   1   1.7
2   U1077   132825  2   2   2   2.0
3   U1077   135060  1   2   2   1.7
4   U1068   135104  1   1   2   1.3
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
1249    U1043   132630  1   1   1   1.0
1250    U1011   132715  1   1   0   0.7
1251    U1068   132733  1   1   0   0.7
1252    U1068   132594  1   1   1   1.0
1253    U1068   132660  0   0   0   0.0
1254 rows × 6 columns
```